# angular - hiding form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a `<h4>` that has an item Title, if you click on the title then it turns into a textbox with submit and cancel buttons.  I have all that working , my problem is *Trying to hide the form after the ajax reguest*

html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="editThis">
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="topic.TopicName" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2 pull-right">
      <input type="button" class="btn-xs btn-success btn" ng-click="editDetails(topic)" value="submit" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2 pull-right">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="cancel" ng-click="editThis = false" />
   </div>
```

see I use `$scope.editThis` to determine weather to show the  or the

i do not know why this is not working.

```
 $http.post("/MyVault/EditTopic", { topicEditId: item.VaultTopicId, topicEditName: item.TopicName, topicEditDescription: item.TopicDescription })
                .then(function(data, status, headers, confis) {
                    $scope.editThis = false;  // never gets reflected in view


            });
```

Comment: Does the POST call definitely succeed? Check in the Network tab of the devtools to make sure. The reason I ask is that you have only assigned a success handler for the call, so if it errors out, then nothing will happen.

Comment: it definetly succeeds

Comment: If I put the debugger on that line , it executes it just fine , the view never reflects the changes though

Comment: Can you reproduce this using something [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co), [jsBin](http://jsbin.com), [CodePen](http://codepen.io) or the inbuilt snippet support on SO? I suspect something else is introducing a new scope somewhere so you end up with two different `editThis` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo here http://jsbin.com/saduju/4/edit

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('firstCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.topics = [
            {TopicName: "First Topic" }, 
            {TopicName: "Second Topic"},
            {TopicName: "Third Topic"}
            ];


        $scope.editDetails = function (topic) {

            $http.post("/MyVault/EditTopic", {
                topicEditName: topic.TopicName
            })
            //success calback
            .then(function (data, status, headers, confis) {
            })
            //error calback
            .then(function (error) {
            })
            //finally calback
            .then(function () {
            //--change editThis to topic.editThis

                topic.editThis = false;

            });


        };
    });
```

html:

```
 <body ng-app="app">
      <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="topic in topics" >
           <!--change topic to topic.editThis-->
      <h4 ng-click="topic.editThis=true">{{topic.TopicName}}</h4>
          <!--change topic to topic.editThis-->
        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-show="topic.editThis">
       <div class="col-xs-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="topic.TopicName" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 pull-right">
          <input type="button" class="btn-xs btn-success btn" ng-click="editDetails(topic)" value="submit" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 pull-right">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" value="cancel" ng-click="editThis = false" />
       </div>
      </div>
          </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: any idea why the last promise would work and not the suddess?

Comment: I don't believe that is the correct way to add success and error handlers using `.then()` on the [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). It should take up to 2 arguments, one for the success handler and one for the error handler.

Comment: @ScottSelby more likely some error occurs, if you put that in finally callback doesn't matter what happens editor should disappear

Comment: @ScottSelby what version of angular are you using ? Have you checked that bin ?

Comment: The reason this works in the jsBin is that jsBin does not return an error for the POST request, and the `.then()` function only adds success handlers with the way it has been used here.

Comment: @ScottSelby are you using ng-repeter ? if yes please see that demo  http://jsbin.com/saduju/3/edit

Comment: That is not actually an error callback, @sylwester is unfortunately mistaken. That jsBin does not prove that it works. Is the markup in the jsBin your exact markup, though? You haven't removed something for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: yes - it's in ng-repeat , I can't even get the jsBin to work correctly

Comment: it looks like adding the property to each individual item int the repeat will do it , but why can't I have a property assigned to scope and just hide them all ?  Like if I was using jQuery I would have a class for all of them and just hide them all in one line

Comment: @ScottSelby because ng-repeter creating new scopes as GregL mention in his comments

Comment: @ScottSelby If you don't have an `editThis` property per topic, you would click one of them and suddenly be editing all of them. That is likely not what you want. Since you only want to edit one at a time, you need to put that property on each element in your array, there is no other way around it.

Comment: Your answer did not solve my question , but the comments did - basically I had to have a separate prop for each item in the foreach iteration.  I have no idea WHY this is the case , but none the less it worked.